# Miro and Flash Player problem

Tags: flash, miro

I have just installed Ubuntu and it's great. I  also installed Flash by following [these instructions](http://ubuntuguide.net/install-adobe-flash-plugin-in-ubuntu-12-04both-3264-bit).

After I wanted to download a video from Youtube and I installed a software called Miro that looks like some sort of browser. When i navigated to Youtube it says no Flash Player downloaded. But if I use Firefox, Youtube  works fine.
Help pls

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative to Miro that may be of help. Firefox has an [addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=search) called "Download Video Helper" -- You can download streaming video with that.